# How to handle client expectations regarding page building and layout within Craft

Tags: matrix, content, blocks, layout

I love Craft CMS and use it for nearly every site I build. There isn't a better tool (in my opinion) for managing custom data.

And using a matrix field as content builder solves the majority of my client's publishing needs.

But with so drag and drop page building tools on the market, I find that sometimes clients expect to find the same drag and drop page layout ability within Craft as they would find in Squarespace or Weebly or Mail Chimp Templates.

Other than educating a client that Craft is not a layout tool and there are times when you use different tools for different jobs, what solutions do you suggest?

Is there a way to accomplish minimally viable layout with becoming very dependent on plugins?

Is there are way to use a 3rd party page builder and embed the content in Craft?

Or is best not to even try?

Have you approached handling client's layout expectations within Craft CMS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question comes up in support tickets every so often from client users.

We like to say that Craft fills the space between where WordPress ends and Enterprise begins. It's meant for designers and developers to build bespoke websites for clients. That would include Squarespace-like website building services as well.

If your design, technical, and business requirements exceed what Squarespace can offer then they naturally exceed what a drag/drop website builder can provide. If there's anything a client wishes for in the control panel then they can ask their agency or developers about feasibility. Craft is extensible enough to make most thing possible; it's just a matter of effort and cost.